# CSS Hidden div with over image

Tags: javascript, html, css

here I have a big problem.

I try to cover a div by an image, so that it is disabled, except that I can not adapt to the size of the window, I managed to produce a code, here is the result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMY53.png

and sometimes it gives this bug: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxRW7.png in both cases, the image is not centered from the top, I tried full value (all that between 20 & 30) but it does not help ..

Here is my code:

```
  var width=$('.soon').width();
  var height=$('.soon').height();

  $('.soonIMG').css('width', width);
  $('.soonIMG').css('height', height);
  $('.soonIMG').css('top', -height-20.5);

$( window ).resize(function() {

  var width=$('.soon').width();

      var height=$('.soon').height();

      $('.soonIMG').css('width', width);
      $('.soonIMG').css('height', height);
      $('.soonIMG').css('top', -height-20.5);
});
```

How to solve the problem? Thank you all!

Comment: Actually I don't understand what u want to do

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, you want to place an image over a `div` to kinda block the content on the `div` from being clicked with the image?

Comment: Yes IvanS95 that's it! ! Sorry for my bad explain :/

Comment: What's `474/5000`?

Comment: Ok, let me ask, what exactly is the behavior you expect? You could just position the image on the screen with CSS so it stays on top of the content, then just toggle its visibility with JavaScript instead of defining its size with JS only

Comment: j08691 I put it unintentionally during an edict.


Freestyle09, I tried to re-explained on my first post, hoping it's better ^^

IvanS95 I would like that when you change the size of the screen (when you zoom, or for different device), the window fits, without overflowing on the nav bar, except that every time it goes in anything

Thank you for trying to understand me, sorry to explain wrong: /

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your description, I understood like you want to block a specific div with some kind of image. So here I've given some CSS with this you can achieve that.

**CSS**

```
.overlay {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    z-index: 999;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
```

And place the following HTML in the div which you want to block with image.

```
<div class="overlay">
<!-- Here you can add HTML for the image/content which you want to show on that div and write CSS for that as well -->
</div>
```

Hope this helps for you, and let me know if any further changes/suggestions needed for this.